# How to display a data table values in html table using angular js

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have a DataTable in OrderDetails.aspx.vb

```
Public Outlets As New DataTable
Outlets = objOrdersData.GetOnlineConfigCall()
```

In my OrderDetails.aspx

```
<script>
var Outlets = '<%=Outlets%>';
</script>
```

I want to display outlets details in a html table using AngularJS

I defined my html table as

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr> <th>Outlets</th>   
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="outlet in Outlets">
<td><a >{{outlet.PartnerName}}</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

but it's not working.

Comment: 1) You need to assign ```Outlets``` to a variable of your controller.  2) ```data-ng-repeat``` should be ```ng-repeat```

Comment: how can i assign outlets to a controller variable ?

Comment: not clear, Explain clearly.

Comment: "You need to assign Outlets to a variable of your controller". How can i do this?

Comment: OrderApp.controller("OrderCntrl", function ($scope, $window, $http) {
    debugger;
     var Outlets = $window.Outlets;
    alert(Outlets[0].PartnerName);
});
this is my controller code. But the alert shows that its undefined.

Comment: please share your controller code

Comment: OrderApp.controller("OrderCntrl", ['$scope', '$window', '$http', function ($scope, $window, $http) {
    debugger;
  
    var Outlets = $window.Outlets;
    alert(Outlets[0].PartnerName);
}])

Comment: when im using : alert(Outlets); then it shows : Table (I mean Table is my table name. So it shows my table name )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `Outlets` is a valid js array, you just need to assign it to scope variable in your controller like:

```
OrderApp.controller("OrderCntrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) { 

  $scope.outlets = Outlets;

}]);
```

and then bind your data in the template like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="outlet in outlets">
  <td><a >{{outlet.PartnerName}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: its not working.  $scope.outlets = Outlets; it returns only the table name. not the table content

Comment: how does ```Outlets``` look like? Is it an array or a table name (string)?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhk9g.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLtDs.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJvML.png Please find out my screenshots

Comment: Outlets is a datatable it binds in page load event

Comment: A datatable is not a valid js array; you should serialize to JSON it if you want to you use it in JS.

Comment: I dont know how to convert datatble to JSON. Shall i use Json.parse(Outlets)

Comment: Sorry but I'm not a .NET expert; just google "vb.net json serialize datatable" and you will find lots of results.